# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser не парсит некоторые страницы

Tags: php, парсер, simple-html-dom

Использую шаблонный код:

```
require_once 'library/simplehtmldom.php';
$html = file_get_html('https://prnt.sc/lzz0dq');
echo $html;
```

Все другие рандомные сайты выводит без проблем, но тот, что сейчас в коде - никак не хочет. Возвращает bool(false) и все

проверял ini_get('allow_url_fopen') - возвращает 1.

Все форумы переискал - ничего.

Comment: Парсер тут не виноват. Возможно prnt.se видит, что ваш запрос не похож на пользовательский и вырубает. Мне он возвращает 403 -- доступ запрещён.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

prnt.sc не так прост, как кажется. Он не хочет чтобы его парсили и защищается тем, что проверяет заголовки запроса. Я добавил в запрос заголовок `User-Agent`, скопированный из моего браузера, и получил ответ 200.

Притворитесь браузером и получите ответ.

Как добавить заголовки уже знают на so https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945511/seting-user-agent-param-in-php-simple-html-dom-parser

Comment: Спасибо. Я сразу после поста попробовал этот способ и получилось. Ответ правильный)